# Closing fancybox iframe from link and open a gallery

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

This is my scenario: I have a page (index.php) where I can open a fancybox image gallery by clicking on an image or a link and I have another link where I can open a fancybox iframe.

I'd like to close the fancybox iframe and open a fancybox gallery with a manual link from iframe page.

### index.php

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.11.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/functions.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

<a class="fancy-gallery" rel="gl_82" href="82_1.jpg"><img src="82_1.jpg"></a>
<a class="fancy-gallery" rel="gl_82" href="82_2.jpg"><img src="82_2.jpg"></a>
<a class="fancy-gallery" rel="gl_82" href="82_3.jpg"><img src="82_3.jpg"></a>

<a class="fancy-open-gallery" data-open-id="gl_82">Open Gallery</a>

<a class="fancy-open-iframe" data-url='iframe.php'>Open Iframe</a>
```

To close the fancybox iframe I tried these 2 methods.

### iframe.php

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.11.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/functions.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

<a id="close-btn" data-open-id="gl_82">Close iframe via JQ</a>
<a onclick="parent.closeFancybox('gl_82');">Close iframe and open gallery</a>
```

btn-close function, is not invoked, while the function closeFancybox (out of DOM) closes the fancybox correctly, 
but does not open the gallery.

### function.js

```
$('.fancy-gallery').fancybox({
type: 'image',
    helpers: {
        title: {
        type: 'over'
        }
    }
});


$('.fancy-open-iframe').fancybox({
    'type': 'iframe',
    beforeLoad: function() {
        var url = $(this.element).data('url');
        var uid = $(this.element).data('uid');
        this.href = url + '?uid=' + uid;      
    }
});

$('.fancy-open-gallery').click(function(e) {
    var el, id = $(this).data('open-id');
    if(id){
        el = $('.fancy-gallery[rel=' + id + ']:eq(0)');
        e.preventDefault();
        el.click();
    }
});

$('#close-btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    parent.$.fancybox.close();
});


}); <!-- end DOM -->

function closeFancybox(relid){
    $.fancybox.close();
    var el, id = relid;
    if(id){
    el = $('.fancy-gallery[rel=' + id + ']:eq(0)');
        e.preventDefault();
        el.click();
    }       
}
```

What could be the problem? How could I do? Thanks

Comment: How many galleries do you have?

Comment: Galleries are automatically generated and can be up to 10